# I deployed my react project to github, but the page is empty without any errors. Why?

Tags: reactjs, github, deployment

I did everything I was supposed to do, and have done trillions of times before, and it always works, but now it doesn't. Why??

```
git init
git git remote add origin <name>
git branch -M main
git push -u origin main
npm run deploy
git add .
git commit -m 'commiting'
git push origin main
```

I added the `"homepage"`, `"predeploy"` and `"deploy"` in the package json file.

On github, it says it's deployed, but when I click the URL, the page is empty. The title of my website is showing, the react icon is there, but the page is empty. When I refresh, the console just shows this: `Error with Permissions-Policy header: Unrecognized feature: 'interest-cohort'.`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244131/discussion-on-question-by-controlfreakshater-i-deployed-my-react-project-to-gith).

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore the error message! This is because to Google's new tracking technology called FLoC is blocked. You can read more about FLoC here https://web.dev/floc/

https://github.blog/changelog/2021-04-27-github-pages-permissions-policy-interest-cohort-header-added-to-all-pages-sites/